# Faithful representation of $C_c(X \times X)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, groupoids

> Let $X$ be a smooth manifold. $X \times X$ is product manifold. $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $X$.

There are two aims

(i) Associate a $C^*$ norm to $C_c(X\times X)$, making it a $C^*$ algebra.

(ii) Show that this is in fact $*$-isomorphic to $K(L^2(X,\mu))$ the compact operators on $L^2(X,\mu)$.

> $$ \pi:C_c(X\times X) \rightarrow B(L^2(X,\mu)), \quad \pi(f)(\xi)(x) = \int_{z \in X} f(x,z)\xi(z) \, d\mu (z) $$ 
>   This representation induces a norm on $C_c(X \times X)$.

I guess this is how (i) works. We have a

(a) a $*$-algebra homomoprhism.

This follows as 
$$\pi(f\ast g) \xi(x) = \int_z \int_yf(x,y)g(y,z) \xi(z) dy \, dz $$ 
$$ \pi(f) \pi(g)\xi (x)  = \int_y f(x,y)\int_z g(x,z) \,dz dy = \int_y\int_z f(x,y)g(x,z) \xi(z) \, dy dz $$ 
(a') which is also injective: Firstly, $f|_x$ is a measurable function, so the integral makes sense. Secondly if $f|_x:X \rightarrow \Bbb C$ when tested against all $\xi \in L^2(X,\mu)$, yields $0$ integral, then $f|_x$ is zero. Hence $f$ is zero.

(b)Now this is a faithful representation. Hence we can give a norm on $C_c(X \times X)$ by 
$$||f||_1 = ||\pi(f)||_{op}$$
This is a $C^*$ norm. We take the completition.

(c) Now I wish to understand the compact operators on $L^2(X,\mu)$ for (ii). It suffices to show the image of $\pi$ is dense.

Remark: It seems that the problem is not well stated too, and the result seems to be a consequence of [Hilbert Schimdt Operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator) - that the image lies in $K(L^2(X,\mu)$. That it is dense is not clear.

---

The source of this example is [Example 4 at Page 18](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3617)

Comment: Hmm, how is $\mu$ defined? What do you mean by $\|f\|$? Is it $\|f\|_\infty$ or $\|f\|_2$? And if the latter, why is $C_c(X\times X)\subset L^2(X\times X,\mu)$? So, my main confusion is the "smooth manifold"...

Comment: If you mean $\|f\| = \|f\|_\infty$, then the statement is definitely wrong.

Comment: I believe its $||f||_2$. And $||\pi(f)||$ is operator norm.

Comment: For "Haar measure" to make sense, $X$ should actually be a Lie group, or at least some sort of homogeneous space.

Comment: @amsmath After a day, I finally understand your first question.  My problem is nonsense, let me  edit it.

Comment: To above, I have edited my question, does my question make sense now?

Comment: Yes, each $\pi(f)$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt (HS) operator and hence compact. BTW, $\mu(K)$ should be finite for every compact $K\subset X\times X$. Otherwise, the integral does not make sense. Concerning the density: For $k\in L^2(X\times X)$ denote $(T_kg)(x) := \int_Xk(x,y)g(y)\,d\mu(y)$. Then each HS operator in $L^2(X)$ is of that form. Let $k\in L^2(X\times X)$ and $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then there exists $f\in C_c(X\times X)$ such that $\|k-f\|_2 <\epsilon$. Hence, $\|T_k-\pi(f)\| = \|T_k-T_f\| = \|T_{k-f}\|\le\|k-f\|_2 < \epsilon$. So, your image is dense in HS.

Comment: And as $HS(L^2(X))$ is dense in $K(L^2(X))$ (each finite rank operator is HS), your image is dense in $K(L^2(X))$. ---- But why is $\|fg\|_1\le\|f\|_1\|g\|_1$? You need that for $C_c(X\times X)$ to be a normed algebra.

Comment: Does not that follow from : (i) we have an algebra homomorphism and (ii) we defined the norm from the image algebra?

Comment: @amsmath, which part of ^ of my argument breaks?

Comment: @W.Zhan It is true if you prove that $\|\pi(fg)\|\le\|\pi(f)\|\|\pi(g)\|$. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I thought $B(L^2(X))$ is a $C$ $*$-algebra.

Comment: If you have operators on a hilbert space $H$, $||TS|| \le ||T|| \, ||S||$. Am I missing something? My understanding is that we defined the map to be isometric in the first place.

Comment: Is $\pi(fg) = \pi(f)\pi(g)$?

Comment: I haven't checked but it is claimed in the original pdf (i linked) that this the convolution product on $C_c(G \times G)$ (making at an involutive algebra) defined by yields an algebra homomorphism. I will try write this out when I return.

Comment: amsmath, are the calculations in the edit correct?